# Why can Android range more beacon regions than iOS?

Tags: android, monitoring, ibeacon, scanning, beacon

According to a test from Radius Network [1], iOS devices can only detect up to 30 beacon regions in monitoring mode. But why is it on Android still possible to define an (almoast) infinite number of beacon regions?

Thanks for clarification.

[1] http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/04/21/max-beacon-regions-ios.html

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, there are actually two limits on iOS:

- **Each iOS app can monitor for a maximum of 20 defined `CLBeaconRegion`s.  This limit is a holdover from a maximum 20 geofences per app.**  Because Apple extended the same APIs, the limit of 20 `CLRegion`s per app was inherited by beacons because the `CLBeaconRegion` object is a specific type of `CLRegion`.  There are probably other reasons that Apple decided to keep this same limitation with beacons, but this is where it originated.
- **The first 30 CLBeaconRegions registered on a device (across all apps) get accelerated detection.**  This is because the bluetooth chips have limited hardware slots for hardware matching of BLE packets.  If all these slots are taken, detection falls back to periodic software scanning, which is slower.

On Android these exact limits do not apply, but other limitations do exist.  The following restrictions apply for the Android Beacon Library:

- **There is no limit on the number of regions you can monitor.**  However, because matching is ultimately done in software, monitoring an extreme number of regions (many hundreds or thousands) will slow down your app and may cause performance problems.
- Hardware acceleration filters work only on Android 5.0+ (if available on the phone hardware).  They are applied against the beacon type, not the specific beacon region.  So while **there are no region limits on accelerated hardware detection, if multiple beacons are visible at the same time, your app only gets accelerated detection for the first beacon that becomes visible**.  Subsequent detections fall back to slower periodic software scanning, like on iOS, until all beacons disappear.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually 20 Beacon regions that iOS can monitor and it's simply a limitation introduced by Apple to CoreLocation framework.

There's no official explanation of the reason, but my guess would be that Apple doesn't want devs to monitor a large/infinite quantity of regions to avoid abusing that feature and having a negative impact on the device's battery life.